# Scipy stats t-test for the means and degrees of freedom

Tags: python, probability, scipy.stats

I am using the stats module from scipy and in particular the function `ttest_ind`. I want to extract information related to the degrees of freedom when I apply this test. According to the SciPy v1.11.4 documentation, [link](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ttest_ind.html#scipy-stats-ttest-ind), it is mention that the following values are return:

- **statistic**: t-statistic
- **pvalue**: p-value associated with the given alternative
- **df**: degrees of freedom used in calculation of the t-statistic

However using the following reproducible example I don't see that this is possible:

```py
from scipy.stats import ttest_ind

# Example data for two groups
group1 = [25, 30, 22, 28, 32]
group2 = [18, 24, 20, 26, 19]

t_statistic, p_value, degrees_of_freedom = ttest_ind(group1, group2, permutations=None)
#> Traceback (most recent call last):
#> Cell In[6], line 1
#> ----> 1 t_statistic, p_value, degrees_of_freedom = ttest_ind(group1, group2, permutations=None)
#> ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)
```

It is an error in the documentation or there is a way to obtain the degrees of freedom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part right before explains how to handle this:

> Returns:
>
> resultTtestResult
> An object with the following attributes:

In other words, the function returns an object containing the data, rather than a tuple containing the data.

You can get the data out of that object like so:

```
from scipy.stats import ttest_ind

# Example data for two groups
group1 = [25, 30, 22, 28, 32]
group2 = [18, 24, 20, 26, 19]

result = ttest_ind(group1, group2, permutations=None)
print("t", result.statistic)
print("pvalue", result.pvalue)
print("df", result.df)
```

Comment: Thank you @Nick Odell for your help. I was confused taking into account that:

t_statistic, p_value = ttest_ind(group1, group2, permutations=None)

works. I will need to be careful in the  future when extracting the values of an object as a tuple.